# C-Style casting causing SIGILL, dynamic_cast ok

Tags: c++, g++

In a project of mine here I have a class that implements four interfaces:

```
class A : public B,
          public C,
          public D,
          public E
{
  ----Implementation Code here----
};
```

these four interfaces contains only pure virtual functions, none of them compose the diamond problem (so I don't need to use the *virtual* keyword) so I spected no problem when doing something like this:

```
A* var = new A;
((C*)var)->method_from_interface();
```

Yet something ugly is happening, because the function is jumping around to a different method of the A class, and valgrind complains about an unhandled instruction. However, doing this:

```
 A* var = new A;
(dynamic_cast<C*>(var))->method_from_interface();
```

works as suspected.

So I'm wondering if this is a G++ bug or some misuse of the language?

edit:

Maybe I've simplified too much my problem. I'm receiving the A class as a D* on a function call:

```
void do_something(provider* p) {
   D* iface = p->recoverItemByName("nameThatReturnsClassA");
   ((B*) iface)->call_method_from_b_iface();
}
```

Note that I know that in this time the D* is in fact an A*, so casting doing a casting to B* isn't breaking any rules. I can't static_cast it, though, as D* and B* have no relation, but I can use reinterpret_cast successfully.

Comment: Don't use C-style casts.

Comment: Why do you need that cast anyway, and what method _in C_ would you call? You stated that the base classes contain only pure virtual functions. This means that any implementation of any function you could _possibly_ call without crashing must be _in A_ (or a class derived from A, or some other class derived from one or several of the bases, implementing the interface). Thus, if you have an object of type A, why cast to something else?

Comment: @Damon I've simplified the problem. In fact I'm receiving the A* object as it's interface from method that's manages it. I have no access to A where I'm using it.

Comment: @scooterman: But still, the fact remains that `class C`  does not have an implementation of the pure virtual functions. Any class derived from it must by definition implement the pure virtual function(s), but the interface class itself does not have it. Thus, telling the compiler "call that (nonexistent) function on an object of type C" is quite certainly bad mojo. If anything, this should produce the message "terminate called after pure virtual function call" on the screen, never anything else. The "but it works with static_cast" part is what's truly worrying, because it _must not_ work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that I know that in this time the D* is in fact an A*, so casting
>   doing a casting to B* isn't breaking any rules.

Wrong.

*You* may know that it's actually an A*, but the compiler doesn't, at least at compile time when it's trying to figure out what code to emit to do the conversion.

A funny thing happens when you inherit from multiple classes with virtual methods. When you convert from the derived class to one of the interface classes, the pointer address changes! The compiler does adjustments to the pointer to make it valid for the pointer type you've declared. Try it yourself, start with an `A*` pointer and display its value, then cast to a `B*`, `C*`, and `D*` and display those. At most one of the base classes will be the same as the `A*`, the others will be different.

When you use a C-style cast you're telling the compiler "I don't care if you can't do the conversion properly, do it anyway." It duly treats the `D*` as a `B*` without doing the required fixups, so now the pointer is completely wrong. It isn't pointing to the class B vtable so the wrong methods get called.

A dynamic_cast works because it uses extra information available at run-time; it can trace the pointer to its most-derived `A*` and then back down to a `B*`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, very well described. To contextualize more, what I'm trying to do is a Plugin architecture. In my example, A would be a plugin implementation, and B would be the Plugin interface, C and D other interfaces that the plugin implements. I was wondering what would be the best way to approach this problem, as the function call is when I'm loading another plugin that depends on A, and would only know the interfaces A implements, since them could be in different shared libraries loaded at runtime.

Comment: @scooterman, you have two choices. You can rely on dynamic_cast, or you can put a method in interface B that gives access to other interfaces. I wouldn't allow access to A directly, create a new interface if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

C-style cast is just doing a "basic" memory mapping of your pointer to your class. If your method is offset=42 in your class, it would make (*(A+42)) () (simplified, of course).

however, if you inherit from more than one class, you have to take into account the various classes and order in which the compiler puts them.

static_cast is taking into account multiple inheritance.

On your example, it would probably work with either B,C,D or E, but not with the other ones. However, you have no good reason to do that : you would call `A->methodFromInterface()` and it just works!

On C++, it's advised to use static_cast or dynamic_cast (note : second one relies on rtti which might not be available) and discard the old C-style cast.

*EDIT*
Tried to reproduce issue but couldn't, files can be found on

- class2.hpp : http://pastebin.com/CBVykqcD
- class2.cpp : http://pastebin.com/Vy2YsEGP
- class.cpp : http://pastebin.com/wwHpe87g

Compiled with on MacOs 10.6:

```
g++ -fno-rtti -o truc ./class.cpp ./class2.cpp && ./truc
```

Comment: Although C-style cast is bad, what it does is to try `const_cast`, `static_cast`, `static_cast`+`const_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`+`const_cast` in order. If `static_cast` works but C-style cast doesn't, it's more likely a bug of gcc.

Comment: @KennyTM: In my opinion, the fact that `static_cast` _works_ is a bug, if anything. Calling a pure virtual function (which is what you do by downcasting) cannot work, should not work. The function doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your function do_something.

This line is fine:

```
D* iface = p->recoverItemByName("nameThatReturnsClassA");
```

But this line is bad because B is not related to D, so you cannot cast safely. Try calling static_cast(iface) and you will see the compiler complaining - which should be a warning to you.

```
((B*) iface)->call_method_from_b_iface();
```

In the upper line you are coding knowledge that iface does not only point to a D, but to an A. Better store the a pointer to A and use that pointer. So do

```
A* iface = p->recoverItemByName("nameThatReturnsClassA");
iface->call_method_from_b_iface();
```

If you still want to stick to D* iface, then code it like this (with only one the both options):

```
D* iface = p->recoverItemByName("nameThatReturnsClassA");
static_cast<A*>(iface)->call_method_from_b_iface();  // option 1, easy to understand
dynamic_cast<B*>(iface)->call_method_from_b_iface(); // option 2, will do a cross-cast
```

For more information about dynamic_cast and it's cross cast capability see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cby9kycs.aspx.

Last but not least: try to avoid old C-style cast and always try to use the C++ style cast const_cast, static_cast/dynamic_cast and reinterpret_cast (in this order).

Comment: Emphasis: B is not related to D. The compiler doesn't know that the pointer points to part of an `A` object, so it doesn't know how to properly do the conversion. A C-style cast tells the compiler "I don't care if you can't do the conversion, do it anyway." Hilarity ensues. A dynamic cast traces the pointer back up to its parent A then back down to B, so it succeeds.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the cross cast, I edited my answer to emphasize this.